# Exported Variables not work outside zsh functions

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I try to set function in zshrc file and call it when I need specific variables. But when I invoke this function there are no variables that I can use:

.zshrc file:

```
# .zshrc file

function c() {
  (
    export TEST=/tmp/just.log
  )
}
```

So when I invoke c() inside shell there is no TEST var.

how do I enable this functionality?

Comment: Why do you have export line enclosed in ()?

Comment: Actually, it is not even available inside `c` itself. It is available in the child process which you unnecessarily create inside your function `c`.

Comment: The subshell doesn't necessarily *need* to start a subprocess, but since `export` doesn't do anything except add an attribute to the name `TEST`, the *assignment* to `TEST` cannot affect the value of `TEST` outside the subshell. (It's commonly believed that `export` somehow "injects" a value into the environment; it does not. It simply marks the name to be added to a child process's environment, using whatever value the variable has at that time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the brackets and it should work.

The brackets create a subshell which prevent your variable from being visible.

see https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html and search for subshell

```
# .zshrc file

function c() {
    export TEST=/tmp/just.log
}
```